# settings.gradle file did not showing in Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I create a gradle project in IntelliJ, but settings.gradle file did not showing in intellij and when I want to create it this message shows:

> A file with name 'settings.gradle' already exists

when I look at my project in explorer I found settings.gradle there, but it is not showed in the Project view in IntelliJ.

Comment: Add screenshot showing your project tool window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If you have my problem, you should go to

```
File -> Setting -> Editor -> File Types
```

and delete what you want in "ignore files and folders" section.